# If I can't choose same or similar password as previously, is it stored in plaintext somewhere?

Tags: passwords

The title actually says it all, but I'll write my thoughts as a piece of context here.

From what I understand, the de facto method of storing passwords at the moment of writing is by salting and the hashing (correct me if I'm wrong), the point of this being that the passwords are not stored in plaintext anywhere, and the salt prevents rainbow-table attacks and such. I'm not super proficient on this, but this information I've gathered from the web.

Okay so, it's again time to change a password. If I choose the same password, the salted hash will match and I will get a prompt that says the password is the same as previously. Now some systems also prevent you from setting your password to e.g. 50% or 70% similar to your previous password, or one of your previous passwords.

I believe this to be fine security-wise, but how is this done if the passwords are not stored in plaintext anywhere? Or are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer may be simpler than you think, often you have to enter the old password together with the new one to change it, so the application gets the old password from the user. This is actually a good thing security-wise, because only a user knowing the old password can change it to another one.

Answer (score 1):

As @martinstoeckli says, the simplest answer is that you usually have to enter your previous password when you change your password - so it can just compare the two in memory.

However, it's also possible to check for similar passwords even if the old one is stored hashed, by taking the new password, applying various transformations to it (changing individual characters, reducing the number on the end by one, removing the last character, etc), hashing those permutations, and then comparing those to the previously stored password. If you're using a good password hashing algorithm (bcrypt/scrypt/Argon2id/PBKDF2) then this will be fairly slow, but with faster algorithms then it wouldn't be a noticeable delay.

It's worth noting that these kinds of transformations are commonly used by attackers if they had access to previous passwords, and are also used with wordlists to try and guess variants of common words.